# Rails Engines, mountable apps etc, effect of failure of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, rack-middleware

I assume that if you mount an app in a main rails or use a rails engine. If any of the sub-apps fail/crash than that means the main app and all the sub-app fail/crash.

Does anyone know this for sure? I am wondering if I am building a system if I should separate my architecture into multiple standalone application and instances or build Engine/mountable apps instead of a larger app. The worry is what would happen if part of the app ecosystem goes don't how does it effect the rest of the applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't crash the main app.